Admin User Records not showing 2.3.5
Magento 2.3.5-p2
System> Permissions> All Users show 8 Records Found, however the page is blank with no records showing not even myself as the Admin User. I have a critical issue where I need to delete an unauthorized user for the list ASAP. Not even sure how this user was able to gain access to the site. My host company notified me of this as being a security issue. I am also interested in deleting other users no longer needed in the list.
Can anyone advise how can I get this list to show so I can delete the unwanted users

Please check the database. You can find the admin users from admin_user table.

The issue you're facing is likely due to database corruption, misconfigured user roles, or a bug in Magento 2.3.5-p2 that affects the admin user listing.
